# storing knowledge in team foundation server

Tags: tfs

We use Team Foundation Server.
I was wondering if it's possible to store knowledge in whatever form in TFS. For example, if someone resolves a bug, it would be nice to document the solution and make it available/searchable for others (also in other team projects). The solution can indeed be applicable in other contexts.

We also use Sharepoint, so integration of these two is possible.

Answer (score 6):

For information localized to a workitem (say, a screenshot for a bug, etc.) tieing that data directly to a workitem is the way to go.  For data who's lifespan is beyond that of a workitem (knowledge base stuff, ongoing documentation, etc.) consider sharepoint.

So to your example, if the defect resoultion had some data that was localized and had no real long term value, you would leave it in the workitem for historic reasons - but if it had longer term value, consider tieing this back to Sharepoint (wiki or to some other document), and optionally adding a link between the bug (or other workitem) and the sharepoint article (do this by using a link type of hyperlink).

Another option for searching out some of those workitem specific notes would be to use an extension (i.e. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3f31bfff-5ecb-4e05-8356-04815851b8e7/ ), but IMO for the stuff with long term value, Sharepoint makes a lot more sense.